# Moving symlinks into a folder based on id3 tags

Tags: linux, bash, music, script, id3

I'm trying to get my music folder into something sensible. Right now, I have all my music stored in `/home/foo` so I have all of the albums soft linked to `~/music`. I want the structure to be `~/music/<artist>/<album>` I've got all of the symlinks into `~/music` right now so I just need to get the symlinks into the proper structure. I'm trying to do this by delving into the symlinked album, getting the artist name with id3info. I can do this, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
for i in  $( find -L $i -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n")
do

 echo "$i" #testing purposes

    #find its artist
    #the stuff after read file just cuts up id3info to get just the artist name
 #$artist = find -L $i -name "*.mp3" | read file; id3info $file | grep TPE | sed "s|.*: \(.*\)|\1|"|head -n1

 #move it to correct artist folder
 #mv "$i" "$artist"

done
```

Now, it does find the correct folder, but every time there is a space in the dir name it makes it a newline.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
$ ls 
DJ Exortius/
The Trance Mix 3 Wanderlust - DJ Exortius [TRANCE DEEP VOCAL TECH]@
```

I'm trying to mv `The Trance Mix 3 Wanderlust - DJ Exortius [TRANCE DEEP VOCAL TECH]@` into the real directory `DJ Exortius`. `DJ Exortius` already exists, so it's just a matter of moving it into the correct directory that's based on the id3 tag of the mp3 inside.

Thanks!

PS: I've tried easytag, but when I restructure the album, it moves it from `/home/foo` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe `find` into `while` instead of doing `for $(find)` in order to properly handle filenames with spaces in them.

You can also use process substitution to accomplish the same thing. You would redirect `<(find)` into the `done` part of the while loop.

```
find -L $i -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n" | while read -r i
do
    moving_stuff_around
done
```

Or

```
while read -r i
do
    moving_stuff_around
done < <(find -L $i -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n")
```

The latter has the advantage of not creating a subshell.

Comment: You mean, the former has the advantage of not creating a subshell.  The latter creates a subshell with the use of parentheses.

Comment: @DanielPapasian: It's true that the process substitution is a subshell. However, my first example creates a subshell by piping a command into the `while` and variable changes and directory changes are lost/reverted when the `while` loop terminates. The second does not create a subshell out of the `while` loop so such changes persist after the `while` loop terminates. Bash 4.2 has an option `shopt -s lastpipe` to prevent the creation of a subshell in cases like the first example. Certain other shells (e.g. ksh, zsh) do not create a subshell in the circumstances represented by the first example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use hard links instead of symlinks then you can leave your unordered pool in place while using EasyTAG to restructure the links.

Comment: How would I automatically hard link everything into `~/music` though? I can do a `find . \( -name "*.mp3 -o -name "*.flac" \)` to get all of the songs, but then how would I link automatically to `~/music`?

Comment: `-exec cp -l -t ~/music {} +`